# How to transfert files in a LAN?

Tags: rsync, encryption

I am trying to back up the whole filesystem from one Debian development machine to a NAS on my local network. Over Samba, I am able to achieve (somehow) better than gigabit speeds at 130MBps, however over rsync, I am getting a max of 25MBps. When you have around 100GB of data to transfer, this is obviously taking some serious time!

I can only presume it's the encryption that is slowing things down and as it's local network only, I presume I don't really need encryption.

I am just creating a complete copy of what's on the development machine, so it needs to detect changes and remove them off the destination (which is why I am using rsync).

Here is my current command:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 903" --progress --exclude= {"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / user@IP:/volume1/Backups/NUC --delete
```

I think because I am using non-standard ports it's causing issues.

Is there any way to speed up this transfer at all? Ideally, I'd like to create images of the development machine so it can just be restored if needed but not sure this is possible using cron.

I have added tags like

```
-c arcfour
```

but this seems to cause problems for some reason.

Is there anything better than rsync for just creating a duplication of one system to another as a backup? Or is rsync the right method, just with lower/without encryption?

Comment: Try telling `rsync` to use `rsh` instead of `ssh` - no encryption so faster.  Parameter is `--rsh=rsh`.

Comment: If you want images of the machine take a look at the beta of Veeam Endpoint. Free to use (even professionally) but commercial software.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is probably the `-z` flag. It enables compression. It might sound like a good idea at first. At gigabit connection speed it will take more CPU time to compress than to just transfer the data. Keep in mind that most NAS setups don't have much CPU power, so this is extra expensive here.

Comment: Also consider the `--partial` flag to handle restarted transfers

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I have removed the -z flag but this hasn't made any difference I'm afraid.

Comment: What kind of CPU do you have? Do they have AES NI? Check with `lscpu | grep aes`. My Core i5-2520M has it and it can do lots of AES. Changing the cipher to something else will force the CPU to compute it “by hand” which will be slower.

Comment: I have an i3 Skylake that's about two months old in an Intel NUC. Your command doesn't return anything unfortunately! :(

Comment: What exact CPU is it? You can run `lscpu` and just look at “modules”. If there is no AES thing in there, your CPU has to do AES encryption “by hand”. In that case it should actually free up some performance by using an outdated cipher.

Comment: The output of lspcu shows;  Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz. It's just I get around 25MBps with rsync whereas I get full 125MBps with Samba. I don't need encryption as it's just to a local server but rsync allows me to delete redundant files.

Comment: Please note that this is a self built NAS, running an i3 6100T Skylake, 32GB RAM and I am transferring files from my i3 Skylake NUC to the NAS over LAN.

Comment: According to [Intel Ark](http://ark.intel.com/de/products/90734/Intel-Core-i3-6100T-Processor-3M-Cache-3_20-GHz), your NAS CPU does have AES instructions. So encryption should not really bog it down that much. Can you run `htop` on either side and see what actually takes the load. And it would be nice to know whether it is system or user load.